# Immutable type with function fields in Julia

Tags: math, types, julia

From what I understand, functions are designed to operate on types and not designed to belong to them, but clearly I can just do the following:

```
immutable Sphere
    dimension::Int
    metric::Function
end

sphere = Sphere(2, (x1, x2)->dot(x1, x2))
```

and then I can call this function from inside the type:

```
sphere.metric([1,2],[2,3])
```

Is this bad practice in Julia?  Defining it as `immutable` makes it so I can't change its dimension, but assuming I'm ok with this, it also makes it so I can't change the metric, which mimics the inability to change those methods internal to an object in traditional OOP.

This came up as I was struggling to find the right way to develop a Riemmanian manifold in Julia.  For instance say I have the following code:

```
abstract Manifold

immutable Sphere <: Manifold
    dimension::Int
end

immutable Torus <: Manifold
    dimension::Int
end

metrc(M::Sphere, x1, x2) = ...
metric(M::Torus, x1, x2) = ...
```

Now what if I wanted to put a different metric on my sphere manifold?  There doesn't seem to be a good way to do this using multiple dispatch.  Furthermore conceptually, the Riemannian metric is usually thought of as being part of the manifold's structure, and thus it seems wrong to think about it as a function which takes the manifold as an argument, especially considering the fact that you can put many different metrics on the same manifold.

The better way seems to be to do it like in my original example, where I can instantiate a sphere manifold of immutable type of a specific dimension with a specific metric.  And if I want a new sphere manifold with a different dimension and a different metric then I can just instantiate it.

I guess what I'm asking is, is there a better way to construct manifolds and functions that operate on their points and tangent vectors?  I could forgo defining them at all and instead deal directly with point types and tangent vector types directly, this would follow the Julia paradigm more closely, and there is a post about it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/julia-dev/vv87OW7j3FM/zyfNROpCH5AJ), but it gets pretty hairy.

Comment: This is somewhat similar in spirit to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994384/how-to-get-a-function-from-a-symbol-without-using-eval/28997398#28997398.  You may get some inspiration there.

Comment: @MattB. So as far as I can tell you're saying I should define an abstract metric type, then for each metric have an abstract subtype of the abstract metric type and then turn my manifold into a parametric type `Sphere{T<:Metric}`.  And then use this to make it so I can have multiple dispatch distinguish between different metrics.  This does work but it seems absurdly round about and counter-intuitive compared to simply attaching my function to the Sphere type itself, is there some disadvantage to doing things my way?

Comment: @Thoth while the two approaches are not equivalent and there are trade-offs involved, is any of the two really more round about than the other as you say? in one case you attach a function (admittedly as data), in the other you attach a type (admittedly as a parameter).

Comment: @LucDanton I find it contrived since you have to define this whole other type system just so your function can distinguish between spheres with different metrics.  What would you say is the main trade-off between the two approaches?

Comment: The major difference to me is that if you have two values of type e.g. `Sphere`, they may come with different metrics and you’d have to further refine to figure that out. This may be desirable or not, depending on what you want to do, and only really matters if two or more values of `Sphere` and so on are involved at a time.

Comment: *"is there some disadvantage to doing things my way?"* Yes, right now there can be a substantial performance penalty to storing functions in fields (that may change in the future).  While it may be the best solution in some cases, it's also a code-smell that you may be trying to shoehorn traditional OO techniques from other languages into Julia.  It takes some getting used to, but embracing the separation between data and behavior has simplified a lot of my code.

Answer (score 2):

It is bad practice in Julia to use function typed fields in a composite type to emulate member functions (which are used in may OO languages).

But as I understand your use case, the metric is really to be seen as another field in the `Sphere` type, and not as a member function. So then I wouldn't say it's bad practice.

Then there is the question of efficiency. Right now, storing the metric function in a field will mean that the compiler can pretty much never know which function to call until runtime, incurring quite a lot of overhead at each call. Eventually (in Julia 0.5?) it will be possible to parameterise the `Sphere` type on the function to be stored, which could recover the efficiency compared to other solutions.

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you elaborate on what you mean by parametrizing a type on a particular function?  As far as I understand it, you can parametrize a type, but only with respect to another type, not a particular instance of that type.

Comment: That is true, but there is currently an overhaul in progress that will unify functions and types so that each particular function is represented by a distinct type.

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/13412 And also following the development discussions for a long while, there's probably quite a lot of background on this somewhere on the julia-dev forum (I forget where).

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old thread, but we had a similar problem (actually exactly the same) when designing manifolds in [Manifolds.jl](https://juliamanifolds.github.io/Manifolds.jl/stable/) and we opted for something that I would call “lazy at first”.

So as you did for a type `Sphere <: Manifold` one would implement the inner product (also called Riemannian metric, but it is not a metric more like a metric tensor at every point). This gives any user a nice start to implement an own manifold, and provide for the manifold (thinking of it as a set) a first (and kind of default) metric.

We then designed a `MetricManifold{Manifold,Metric}`, which couples the manifold (again as a set) with a different metric, see for example the linear affine metric on SPDs (https://juliamanifolds.github.io/Manifolds.jl/stable/manifolds/symmetricpositivedefinite.html#Manifolds.LinearAffineMetric) which is the default and the log cholesky metric (https://juliamanifolds.github.io/Manifolds.jl/stable/manifolds/symmetricpositivedefinite.html#log-Cholesky-metric), which is not a default metric thereon

So `SymmetricPositiveDefinite(n)` is the same as `MetricManifold(SymmetricPositiveDefinite(3),LinearAffineMetric())` and to get the manifold with a different metric, use `MetricManifold(SymmetricPositiveDefinite(3),LogCholeskyMetric())`.  Note that you can also have parameters in your metric, so think maybe even of a family of metrics.